# I try to prepare my mediaplayer button before start, but it doesn't work when i clicked on it

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

```
case R.id.rvKick2:
  if (kick2MP.isPlaying()){
     kick2MP.seekTo(0);
  }
  kick2MP.start();
```

this is my code for start mediaplayer. I want to prepare this button first. and i tried this code

```
 case R.id.rvKick2:
        if (kick2MP.isPlaying()){
            kick2MP.seekTo(0);
        }
        kick2MP.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

When i change my code and run the app button didn't work. When i clicked the button my logcat is

```
I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
```

how can i prepare my sound button before start? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you missed to call kick2MP.prepareAsync() method.

Adding setOnPreparedLister, will observe for preparation status call back methods but it not automatically invoke prepare method.